# Iphone and iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I have created an app that is working fine on iPod Touch but is creating problems on iPhone. Is there is any difference in iPhone and iPod Touch that can create problems in running an app. The things that has to be taken care while coding for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, generally "Not at all". Because both iPhone And iPad Touch support the same operating system iOS.

Check out if your iPhone is compatible with the version of iOS code you have developed.

Comment: my iPhone is running on iOS4.3 and my iTouch is running on iOS 4.1 but still i found crashes in iPhone but not in iTouch and i had builded the app for iOS4.1 or higher.

Comment: have you noticed the causes of crash? like access problem memory problem or any thing else., and does your application run properly on simulator?

Comment: I meant on simulator have you tried it running on different version of iPhone-simulator

Comment: thanks i tried to run on different version of iPhone simulator and there were several issues that i  solved and now my app is running nicely on both iPhone and on iTouch.

Comment: Then Accept My answer if you find it helping.. ;), and yeah you can do it by clicking on right mark button beneath my answer.